# "TypeError: Illegal constructor" in Firefox when running CoffeeScript

Tags: firefox, coffeescript

I get the error "TypeError: Illegal constructor" in the console log, when running this CoffeeScript code:

```
class Logger
    constructor (@name) ->

    log: (level, msg) ->
        console.log(level, @name, msg)

    debug: (msg) ->
        log('DEBUG', msg)

new Logger('foo')
```

JavaScript:

```
  Logger = (function() {
    class Logger {
      log(level, msg) {
        return console.log(level, this.name, msg);
      }

      debug(msg) {
        return log('DEBUG', msg);
      }

      info(msg) {
        return log('INFO', msg);
      }

    };

    constructor(function(name) {  // <<--- Firefox throws TypeError here
      this.name = name;
    });

    return Logger;

  }).call(this);
```

Instead, `coffee` should generate this code:

```
Logger =  class Logger {
  constructor(name) {  // <<-- No function() here!
    this.name = name;
  }

  log(level, msg) {
    return console.log(level, this.name, msg);
  }

  debug(msg) {
    return log('DEBUG', msg);
  }

  info(msg) {
    return log('INFO', msg);
  }

};
```

How can I fix this?

The example works in Chrome 75.

Firefox 67.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small typo which is causing the incorrect transpilation into javascript.

```
constructor (@name) ->
```

Should be

```
constructor: (@name) ->
```

The former is interpreted as calling the method constructor and passing it the anonymous function `(@name) ->`. This seems to have confused coffeescript which wrapped the class definition in an immediately executed anonymous function to create a closure from which to use `this` to assign name to.

When corrected your whole class should compile to this which is a lot more legible:

```
var Animal;

Animal = class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  move(meters) {
    return alert(this.name + ` moved ${meters}m.`);
  }

};
```